# ¿Qué significa la utilidad en el servidor de un diagrama de despliegue?

Tags: componentes, despliegue

Holaa!

Tengo una duda, estoy viendo diagramas de despliegue pero no comprendo que quiere "utilidades" en el servidor web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es un componente disponible dentro del nodo Servidor web. Tiene el segundo nombre más genérico posible (aparte de _aplicación_), así que te corresponde averiguarlo con quien hizo el diagrama.